# NotSerializableException for Jackson ObjectNode in Spark closure issue

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson, serializable

Say I have the following Java Object that maps to Jackson full data binding:

```
public class Student implements Serializable{
    private ObjectNode name; // two keys: "first_name", "last_name"

    // getter and setter ...
}
```

And I have a following Spark code that attempts to serialize the closure variable `student` of type `Student` due to different scopes.

```
class A(student : Student) extends Serializable {
    def process(input: DataFrame): Unit = {
        val test = input.map { a =>
            print(student)
        }
    }
}
```

which gives following error: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`

I understand why I am getting such error. Basically, Spark will attempt to serialize all out-of-scope variables a.k.a. closures and pass it to each executors. But since the ObjectNode itself is not `Serializable`, executor cannot get the `Student` instances.

My question is, what are the ways I can solve this?

I have tried using `Map<String, String>` instead of `ObjectNode`, but since `ObjectNode`'s `put` and `set` can only have "primitives" and `JsonNode` as value, it causes error when I try something like this :

```
ObjectNode meta_info = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
meta_info.set("field name", student.getName());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several options.

If you need Object node only for json serialization purpose then you can rewrite your `Student` class and completely remove `ObjectNode`. In your example you can subsitute it by object with `firstName` and `lastName` fields

```
class Name implements Serializable {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

However if this is not possible you can do custom serialization for like this

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private transient ObjectNode name;

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        out.writeUTF(mapper.writeValueAsString(name));
        // other fields here
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(in.readUTF());
        if (!node.isObject()) {
            throw new IOException("malformed name field detected");
        }

        name = (ObjectNode) node;

        // read other fields
    }
}
```

In my example I serialized object node to json string, but you of course can iterate over object node fields store each field separately.

You can read more about custom serialization in [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) javadoc.

Also you can experiment with different [data serializers](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization) like [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making `student` to `Map<String, String>` object, and do `mapper.convertValue(student, ObjectNode.class` whenever I needed it to be in the `ObjectNode`

Answer (score 0):

upgrading to jackson-databind to 10.x helps, refer this https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/18